# WPF HierarchicalDataTemplate TreeView is not Clickable

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a `TreeView` with a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. The items are filled correctly but I can't click on the `TreeView` items. (I can't select one, so that is marked blue).
I can click in front of the `TreeViewItem` and then the selected is marked blue. It looks like there is a small box that I can clicked but the not the rest.

Here is my code:

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Main.TreeItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**Model**

```
public class ITreeItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<ITreeItem> Children { get; set; } 
}

class MainModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<ITreeItem> _treeitems;

    public MainModel()
    {
        _treeitems = new List<ITreeItem>();

        List<ITreeItem> treeList = new List<ITreeItem>();

        ITreeItem myItem1 = new ITreeItem();
        myItem1.Header = "Test1";
        myItem1.Children = new List<ITreeItem>();
        treeList.Add(myItem1);

        myItem1.Header = "Test2";
        myItem1.Children = new List<ITreeItem>();
        treeList.Add(myItem1);

        TreeItems = treeList;          
    }

    public List<ITreeItem> TreeItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _treeitems;
        }
        set
        {
            _treeitems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TreeItems");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, some examples use the TreeViewItem in this way from what I have seen.  I've been stuck for ages with the same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your XAML, instead of using a `<TreeViewItem>` under the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, try using another control, such as a `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
```

Comment: thanks. that works well. is there a waya to expand the items automatically in xaml?

Comment: @user2025830 The way I would do it is create an `bool IsExpanded` Property in your `ITreeItem` class, have the initial value set to `True`, and have that class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well. Then in your `Resources` have a `Style` that targets the `TreeViewItem`.

Comment: @user2025830 Here is the style: <Style  TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>

Answer (score -1):

The previous solution avoids the problem. There is a way to use header to select a `TreeViewItem`: on the MSDN website [we can find an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which uses header and where `TreeViewItem` are clickable. Does someone have an idea why here it's not possible?

I personally hacked that using `MouseButtonEventHandler` adding a `foreach` on items with `isSelected = false;` and then `((TreeViewItem)sender).IsSelected = true;` but that's dirty.

Comment: It's because the OP is using an `ItemTemplate`. When you use an ItemTemplate, a <TreeViewItem> is implicitly created. This explains why TreeViewItems are still generated even though a `TextBlock` is used. It is common practice to use a TextBlock to render TreeViewItems which use templates.